# checkbox prompts multiple time issue on click event having same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page which has multiple checkboxes with the same class name and having value in "id", I post that id value throw ajax. when I Click on the first checkbox It's work fine but one second onwards checkbox it executes the click event for all previously selected checkbox also.

```js
$('.addmycar').on('click', function() {
  var element = $(this);
  var car_id = element.attr("value");
   
 
   alert(car_id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="addmycar" id='BMW' value='1'>
<input type="checkbox" class="addmycar" id='AUDI'value='2'>
<input type="checkbox" class="addmycar" id='HONDA' value='3'>
<input type="checkbox" class="addmycar" id='TATA' value='4'>
```

In the above input checkbox click first on work fine but one-second checkbox it executes two times and so on

Comment: it will execute because you used the selector class and will execute the code for every element with that class. also note that ID should be unique in context

Comment: all Id has a unique value

Comment: just use the the attribute value instead. there are `2 HONDA`

Comment: Ohh sry it's my mistake

Comment: With your edit it seems to work perfectly. Do you want to make only one checkbox selected each time one is clicked?

Comment: instead of `element.attr("value");` you can use `element.val();` or `this.value`